# TCPDF custom font and UTF-8

Tags: fonts, tcpdf, truetype

I have a problem with UTF-8 encoding using a custom font.

I'm trying to generate a document using a TTF imported font.
The font I'm using is a Mac .dfont. I've converted it to ttf using `fondu`.
Then I've added the font to my document using addTTFfont.

```
$pdf->addTTFfont("../fonts/OptimaRegular.ttf", "", "UTF-8", 32, "", 1, 0);
```

Everything works fine with ASCII characters, but nonASCII characters are not diplayed correctly.

If instead I use the dejavusans font everything display correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you install your TTF font on your system, can you use a word processor and use those characters you are interested in successfully with that word processor? Or have you tried another way to make sure your fondu tool correctly converted the font?

Comment: I've installed the font on my Linux box after converting with fondu and then using Libre Office the font works fine

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Has this been addressed yet?

Comment: @Michael no I couldn't find a solution. UTF-8 characters only works with the fonts that comes with tcpdf. In the end I used courier.